# Replace the content of a hg branch

Tags: mercurial, repository, branch

I have a hg repo. I used to have a short-lived branch named "1.x", which stemmed off "default" at a certain point in time. It got closed because I didn't feel the need to use that branch at that particular moment.

However, I was forced to abandon the way "default" was developing and create another branch at a much earlier revision, way before creating "1.x". I was unable to use the name "1.x", so I called it "oldui". The branch "default" was closed as a dead end. I feel uncomfortable with such naming. You can see this in detail in my repository: https://bitbucket.org/mingos/umbracms/changesets/6a3c7980a219

I would like to be able to reuse the branch name "1.x" instead of the cryptic "oldui". How would I go about achieving this, if there is a way at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two big mistakes:

1. You don't read docs: "Standard practice recommends that primary development take place on the 'default' branch." and "2.1. Don't use a name other than default for your main development branch" part from ["What not to do"](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StandardBranching#What_not_to_do) Mercurial wiki
2. You don't read docs: `hg help branch` states clearly

> **Unless -f/--force is specified**, branch will not let you set a branch name that already exists, even if it's inactive.

Comment: 1. I do read the docs. I know it's a bad practice to close the default branch. It's my choice and I'm aware of the consequences. But thanks for bringing this up nonetheless, I'll probably use the default branch name for the "current recommended" version or something. 2. Indeed, I missed this one. Thank you.

Comment: @mingos - you can re-invent the wheel, but *recommended practice* is **recommended because**: tested, used, polished a lot of times and users. Rollbabck to old point in default branch in a) anonymous branch at this point b) merge heads. JFYI

Comment: Yeah, I get the picture. I've already corrected this and now the default branch contains the latest stable revision from the recommended (currently 1.x) version of the application. This will let me develop 1.x and 2.x versions with no odd branch names and the potential users will always get the best useable version. Cheers, mate.

Answer (score 7):

You can just reuse the branch name, although `hg branch` will complain, which you can override with `-f`.

Comment: Thanks, I read that in the man and totally forgot about it. Silly me :).