# SourceTree - make branch the new master

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Im using GIT and Sourcetree as the gui.

I've got two branches - master and feature-01. I now want to overwrite everything on master with whats on feature-01.

I had to do this after having to roll back a few changes on master. however i rolled back the changes on the new branch, got the branch to be 100% where i want master to be but now when i merge the two - master is keeping all the rolled back changes that it should have discarded like in the branch :/

Answer (score 8):

You can do the following:

1. From your `feature-01` branch: `git merge --strategy=ours master`
2. Then from your master branch: `git merge feature-01`

The first command will create a new (merge) commit from the two branches, but ignoring all what's in `master` by using the `--strategy=ours` option. Then, the second command will "advance" `master` to this new commit.

At this point you will have your `feature` contents in `master`. With this option you won't need to "reset" the remote or anything similar; it will just put into `master` all the work you did in `feature`.

Comment: How to do this in SourceTree is the question.

Comment: Wouldn't  `git merge --strategy=theirs feature-01` from the master branch do the same exact thing as those two commands?

Answer (score 5):

> Is this possible in SourceTree?

No, it is not directly possible, because a `merge --ours` is not supported in Sourcetree.
(I have tested it with the latest 2.1.11.0, with Git 2.14.1 embedded, Sept. 2017).

See [`SRCTREEWIN-1237`](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1237) (... from 2013!)

> I need to use the ours strategy i.e. merge myBranch into master, discarding any changes on myBranch

```
git merge -s ours myBranch
```

This is still not available when merging two branches:

[image: merge options]

---

As mentioned in [this article](https://hackernoon.com/lesser-known-git-commands-151a1918a60#f209), you would need to define a custom action:

### [image: custom action]

That will allow you to emulate the `merge --ours` step of the following sequence

```
git checkout feature-01
git merge --strategy=ours master
git checkout master
git merge feature-01
```

The `checkout` and simple `merge` are supported in SourceTree. The custom action allows you to make the `merge --ours` step.
And then, `master` content will be replaced by `feature-01` content.
Entirely from SourceTree alone.

---

For mercurial, following "[Replace the content of a `hg branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9600076/6309)", you would need to create a custom action (as illustrated above), for the command **[`hg branch -f`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Branch#Named_branches)** (the `-f` option is not available in the normal `branch` dialog)

Comment: Thank you. @VonC . I just realized that I am using Mecurial for source control. Is it possible with that as well?

Comment: Also I am confused about discarding changes to mybranch.  Why would I want to do that. I want to replace master with mybranch like the question asks.

Comment: @kirsteng I have updated the answer for mercurial (even though the all page was about Git ;) ). Don't worry about the discard part: the end result is replacing one branch by another. as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SourceTree 3.0

Select `feature-01` branch then pop up a terminal window

[image: SourceTree Terminal Window]

Type in the command `git merge --strategy=ours master` and hit return.
Terminal will prompt for a comment to go with the commit.
It is a Unix Vim editor so to save changes need to
Press Escape key then :x and Enter to save the changes

Close the terminal

Select `master` branch

Open another terminal window and type `git merge feature-01`

(There is probably a way to swap branches from within the terminal window but this worked for me)

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the master branch (it's just a name tagged to a commit), then recreate it where you want it :

```
git branch -d master   // this will delete the branch
git checkout feature-01
git branch master   // this will recreate it where you are checked out.
```

Be careful if you have shared this repository, you have to clean the remote, AND you should probably talk to whoever uses the repository / is in charge of the the repository, because you will be re-writing history.

Comment: This might be OK if `feature-01` and `master` otherwise share the same history.